# No expiry for offline primary PGP key?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, openpgp

Are there benefits to set an expiration date on a PGP primary key which is only used offline?
Is setting an expiration date only on the subkeys enough?

Answer (score 1):

Always set an expiry date on PGP keys. I've learned this the hard way -- I didn't on a few keys I created in my youth while playing around with the tech. I've since lost the keys, so I can't revoke them -- and they still come up when people search me up on keyservers.

Remember that you can always change the expiry date -- you can set it say, 2 years in the future, and when the time comes you can pull the key out of storage and reset the expiry date to give it another two years of life.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

There could be benefits if you envision theft of the key and want to ensure that it cannot be used after a period of time. This is why you'll also want to generate a revocation certificate, but I suppose that could also get lost.

However, the benefits of not having to move around an offline key every year or so could outweigh the benefits of setting an expiration, if that is suitable for your threat model.